# ExtJS4 rtl toolbar issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are upgrading our application to ExtJS4.But we are facing an issue with ExtJS4 toolbar.I want to display the buttons in toolbar as below.

[image: picture1]

But i am getting as below.Any one has idea to achieve the format as shown above?

[image: picture2]

ExtJS3 code is:

```
// Toolbar
Ext.override(Ext.layout.ToolbarLayout ,{
    onLayout : function(ct, target){
        if(!this.leftTr){
            target.addClass('x-toolbar-layout-ct');
            target.insertHtml('beforeEnd',
                 '<table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-ct"><tbody><tr><td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right"><table cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr class="x-toolbar-right-row"></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="x-toolbar-left" align="left"><table cellspacing="0" class="x-toolbar-left-ct"><tbody><tr><td><table cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr class="x-toolbar-left-row"></tr></tbody></table></td><td><table cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr class="x-toolbar-extras-row"></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></td></tr></tbody></table>');
            this.leftTr = target.child('tr.x-toolbar-left-row', true);
            this.rightTr = target.child('tr.x-toolbar-right-row', true);
            this.extrasTr = target.child('tr.x-toolbar-extras-row', true);
        }
        var side = this.rightTr;
        var pos = 0;

        var items = ct.items.items;
        for(var i = 0, len = items.length, c; i < len; i++, pos++) {
            c = items[i];
            if(c.isFill){
                side = this.leftTr;
                pos = -1;
            }else if(!c.rendered){
                c.render(this.insertCell(c, side, pos));
            }else{
                if(!c.xtbHidden && !this.isValidParent(c, side.childNodes[pos])){
                    var td = this.insertCell(c, side, pos);
                    td.appendChild(c.getDomPositionEl().dom);
                    c.container = Ext.get(td);
                }
            }
        }
        //strip extra empty cells
        this.cleanup(this.leftTr);
        this.cleanup(this.rightTr);
        this.cleanup(this.extrasTr);
        this.fitToSize(target);
    }
});
```

These ExtJS rtl you can find in the following URL:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?78419-Extjs-RTL

But in ExtJS4 it is not working.If anyone has idea,share with us.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes i have added code that is in extjs3.please have a look.

Comment: Never used this approach to make toolbars. Have you already tried `for(var i = items.length-1, c; i >=0; i--, pos++)` ?

Comment: no i didnt tried using for loop,not only toolbar i need to display paging toolbar and grid also in reverse like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i came to know that ExtJS 4 is not yet matured to support RTL. Waiting for RTL Support